# Reload collection view data when user comes back to view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Im trying to reload the data every time the view loads but it is not work. code snippet bellow:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Register cell classes
    self.collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.collectionView!.reloadData()
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is only called when the viewController is first created.  Try reloading in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: you place `self.collectionView!.reloadData()` this method in `viewWillAppear ` .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The view did load method is only called when the view is instantiated. It appears that it is not being triggered because your transitions are not deinstantiating the collection view cell. (you might be coming back from a pop over, for example)

To force the reload of the data you could try and put that same line of code under view will appear, which is triggered every time the view is about to be presented to the user.

Try doing:

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

The order normally goes, viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear and then viewDidAppear.

the above code should fix it. let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Isn't there a more performant way by just reloading the cell that was selected?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    self.collectionView!.reloadData()
}
```

This will reload your collection view every time your view controller appears. Also,you donot need to write  reloadData() in viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 1):

1. check to see if collectionview has been initialized.
2. try `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()` after `collectionView.reloadData()`